# Flutter redux Navigator.pop() in StoreConnector after user login

Tags: flutter, redux, flutter-redux

How I can do `Navigator.of(context).pop((route) => false);` on my Login screen?

```
class _LoginState extends State<Login> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  final Store<AppState> store;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  _LoginState(this.store);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StoreConnector<AppState, LoginViewModel>(
      converter: ((Store<AppState> store) => LoginViewModel.create(store)),
      builder: (BuildContext context, LoginViewModel viewModel)  {
        if(viewModel.user.email != '') {
           Navigator.of(context).pop((route) => false);
           return null;
        }
        return (
          viewModel.isLoading ? 
            Center(...)
            :
            Scaffold(...)
```

The above code works but throws the following errors:

```
Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4167:11)
I/flutter (13435): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:6)
I/flutter (13435): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1253:14)
...
```

Comment: Add your whole error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should not call Navigator inside the widget tree hence you are getting an error.

To do so `StoreConnector` has `onWillChange` method. It is a function that will be run on State change, before the Widget is built. (Similar to componentWillUpdate in react class components)

```dart
class _LoginState extends State<Login> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  final Store<AppState> store;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  _LoginState(this.store);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StoreConnector<AppState, LoginViewModel>(
      converter: ((Store<AppState> store) => LoginViewModel.create(store)),
      onWillChange: (LoginViewModel prev, LoginViewModel viewModel) {
        if(viewModel.user.email != '') {
           Navigator.of(context).pop((route) => false);
           return null;
        }
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, LoginViewModel viewModel)  {
        return (
          viewModel.isLoading ? 
            Center(...)
            :
            Scaffold(...)
```

You can explore other methods exposed by StoreConnector in the source code. ([Github Link](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/blob/4197c966c527f7da136bf118b08e2e9429974e47/lib/flutter_redux.dart#L210))

Comment: What if you want to keep your navigation logic in a middleware, how would you then accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you want to navigate while building screen, which is not possible.

add this method.

```
changenavigation() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
       Navigator.of(context).pop((route) => false);
  }
```

change if condition in following way.

```
if(viewModel.user.email != '') {
      changenavigation();
       return Container();
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Accept my answer if it is.

Comment: This is just a hack. Not a proper way to handle it.